# InnoDB - recover mysql database data from ibdata1, ib_logfile0, & ib_logfile1 only

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have converted MyIsam Database to InnoDB.

But for some reason I have by fault chmod 000 InnoDB data directory in mysql data dir (/var/lib/mysql).

Suddenly I found that "innodb_mine" all tables erased, and the database data directory size changed from 5GB to become 400KB!

I have reinstalled Db from old backup but I found that I lost too many things.

Now I'm standing with missing InnoDB database and have the only the following files available :

```
-rw-rw----   1 mysql mysql 5060427776 Jun 12 03:27 ibdata1
-rw-rw----   1 mysql mysql   16777216 Jun 12 03:27 ib_logfile0
-rw-rw----   1 mysql mysql   16777216 Jun 12 03:27 ib_logfile1
```

Now, could I get lost tables from "ib*" files ? how could this be done ?
I will appreciate any help to recover tables data back, as the customer lost one whole year of work!

Comment: I take it there was no automated backup, and someone was just doing a manual one?

Comment: If you have physical access to the server disks then you might be able to run data recovery software on them, but that's a bit of a long shot.

Comment: Do you have the `CREATE TABLEs`?  If so, you _might_ succeed_ with creating the tables in _another_ mysql instance, then copy the `.frm` files back into this broken instance (while mysql is stopped).